# How to use yup validation on dynamic form using react-hook-form with useFieldArray

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, yup, react-hook-form

I'm trying to create a dynamic form using react-hook-form's `useFieldArray` hook. The user should be able to add or remove fields, thus making it dynamic. I've looked at this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhIvi4XHIco) for inspiration, but the missing piece is how to implement error validation to the state, which will be an array of objects: `{email: string}[]`. (The object will take more key/value pairs. I've left out the rest for simplicity.)

I've tried using `yup` as validation schema. It looks like this:

```
const schema = yup.array().of(
  yup.object().shape({
    email: yup.string().email().required(),
  }),
)
```

The implementation into react-hook-form is:

```
import * as yup from 'yup'
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup'
import { useForm, useFieldArray, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'

const { register, control, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
  resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  mode: 'onChange',
})
const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
  control,
  name: 'users',
})
```

The form is more or less according to the tutorial in the link above.

When console logging the `error` object from `useForm` hook it is consistently giving an empty object `{}`. It doesn't seem like it works. I am probably missing something here. The question is what?

Answer (score 9):

**React Hook Form v7**

**yup with dynamic fields react hook form - useFieldArray**

`import { string, object, array } from 'yup';`

```
const formSchema = {
  name: string().required("Name is required").min(7, 'Message'),
};

const schema = object({
  test: array()
   .of(object().shape(formSchema))
});

export default schema;
```

```
const methods = useForm({
  resolver: yupResolver(schema),
});
```

**show the error**

```
<div style={{ fontSize: 14 }}>{errors?.test?.[index]?.name?.message}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code sample, Felipe. I got my dynamic fields validating now .

Answer (score 4):

perhaps you want to use the `context` argument to switch your schema?

> Context: This context object is mutable and will be injected into
> resolver's second argument or Yup validation's context object.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import * as Joi from "joi";

const validationSchema1 = Joi.object({
  username: Joi.string()
    .alphanum()
    .min(3)
    .max(30)
    .required()
});

const validationSchema2 = Joi.object({
  username: Joi.string()
    .alphanum()
    .min(3)
    .max(30)
    .required()
});

const App = () => {
  const [schemaContext, setSchemaContext] = useState({ schemaA: false })
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    context: schemaContext, // use the context switch here
    resolver: async (data, context) => {
      const { error, value: values } = context.is1 ? validationSchema1.validate(data, {
        abortEarly: false
      }) : validationSchema2.validate(data, {
        abortEarly: false
      });

      return {
        values: error ? {} : values,
        errors: error
          ? error.details.reduce((previous, currentError) => {
              return {
                ...previous,
                [currentError.path[0]]: currentError
              };
            }, {})
          : {}
      };
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data)
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>resolver</h1>
      
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" ref={register} />
        {errors.username && <p>errors.username.message</p>}
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the `useForm` hook's resolver property method to identify the validation scheme I should use from the value of a field in my form.

The code below worked for my use case maybe it can help you

```
function formValidatorSchemaByPaymentModalityType(paymentModalityType?: ModalityTypes) {
    switch (paymentModalityType) {
        case ModalityTypes.CREDIT_CARD:
          return creditCardSchemaValidation;
        default:
        return defaultSchemaValidation;
    }
}

const methods = useForm({
    resolver: (data, context, options) => {
      const validatorSchema = formValidatorSchemaByPaymentModalityType(
        data.paymentType.value,
      )
      return yupResolver(validatorSchema)(data, context, options);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should specify your array name. like this:

```
{
  teammates: yupArray().of(
      yupObject().shape({
        email: stringSchemaBuilder("Email").email(),
        expertise: arraySchemaBuilder(false, "Expertise", true, 2, 5),
      })
  ),
};

where teammates is my array name
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by changing the controller name by referring to the [`register` rules documentation](https://legacy.react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/#rules)!

Before:

```
`test[${index}].email`  // incorrect
```

After:

```
`test.${index}.email`  // correct
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const { register, control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm({. resolver: yupResolver(schema),  mode: 'onChange' })

errors[`users[${index}].email`]
```